# stem and leaf plot in R with decimal numbers

Tags: r

I have a problem with the stem- and leaf-plot-function. 
One example:
I want to stem the correlation coefficients of my meta-analysis. Here I have just 2 correlation coefficients (0,056 and -0,022).
I tried the following function:

```
y<-c(0.056, -0.022)
stem(y)
```

and I get the following result:

```
   -2 | 2
   -0 | 
    0 | 
    2 | 
    4 | 6
```

but thats not the right result, it has to be:

```
    0 | 6
   -0 | 2
```

So I don't understand which function I have to use to get the right result.
I would be realy thankful if somebody could help me!

Comment: You can shrink the stem+leaf plot using the `scale` argument (e.g. `scale = 0.2`) but I don't think you're going to be able to reverse the direction of the vertical "axis". That looks like it's built in that way.

Answer (score 2):

Check out `help(stem)` and change the `scale` parameter to control the length of stem plot:

```
R > stem(y, scale = 2)

  The decimal point is 2 digit(s) to the left of the |

  -2 | 2
  -1 | 
  -0 | 
   0 | 
   1 | 
   2 | 
   3 | 
   4 | 
   5 | 6
```

Does that make more sense?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, but it`s not excactly what I wanted.

Comment: I read an articel about stem function in meta-analysis and in this articel the told: If I have the number 0.056, the stem-function takes the 0 (behind the point) and takes the 0 to the front of the symbol |. And the 5 will be rounded to a 6 because the 6 after the 5. And this rounded 6 will come after the symbole 0|. But if I use the stem-function in R, the function takes the 5 and put it before the symbole | and the number 6 it takes behind the symbole |. So, now I am confused which method is wright and which one is wrong!?

Comment: I did not officially learn stem and plot function before, but I checked it out in this [wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stemplot). Both ways seem ok for me, but since -0.022 and 0.056 are in the same scale (two decimal), I get more information from `5|6` than from `0|6`  plus this information `The decimal point is 2 digit(s) to the left of the |`. Since you can control the `scale` parameter in `stem` function, I think it depends on you to get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

The closest I get to your output is:

```
stem(y, scale=0.5, atom=0.1)
```

But it has the negative at the top instead of the bottom.

The first one that you show is a correct answer (the 0.04 and 0.05 stems are grouped together) even if not the desired answer.

Comment: Consider the following stem and leaf plot representing (in cm) the daily growth of a plant in a green house (these are fictitious data).

Tenths Hundredths
0.0 0, 1, 9 
0.1 2, 2, 2, 5, 7
0.2 4
0.3 3, 3, 3, 3, 3
0.4 
0.5 1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 8, 9, 9
0.6 6, 6, 8
0.7 1, 1, 4
0.8 2

From this graph of the data, we can read off the individual values of the original data set: 0.00, 0.01, 0.09, 0.12, 0.12, 0.12, 0.15, 0.17, 0.24, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.33, 0.51, 0.52, 0.52, 0.52, 0.54, 0.58, 0.59, 0.59, 0.66, 0.66, 0.68, 0.71, 0.71, 0.74, 0.82.